# unable to run app in simulator while using view control

Tags: ios

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key segObj.

Comment: please post more details so we can help

Answer (score 1):

Check your references of your outlets in your Storyboard, one of them is probably referencing a property exists more than one time, Otherwise Viewcontroller name does exist or not .

Comment: I guarantee it will be this, especially as its a "segObj" - segue object i guess. So probably best to look for all outlets on the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the "segObj" where it placed . Please add some more code to understand the error. 
Example :
      i faced this error before i added the keypath for uitableview label but i did not call it anymore so it give such crash. Please check it out where it present in your viewcontroller